# jQuery.bind context menu event on two elements overlaid on top of eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `divs` that are on top of each other. What I want is that when the bottom `div` is clicked one context menu appears and when I click the upper `div` I want a different context menu to appear. The `divs` need to remain on top of eachother.

The problem that I am having is that when I click the upper `div` the bind event is executed twice. I believe it is because they are overlaid on top of each other and both `divs` have a bind event attached to them.

Is there a way to only have the bind event execute once on the clicked `div`? Basically give priority to the uppermost (`Z` axis) `div`.

I have an example where you can see that when the red `div` is clicked the `attributeMenu` context menu appears but when you click the green `div` both the `attributeMenu and elementMenu` context menus appear.

Here is the example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2s3p7jp1/1/)

Some of the code:

```
addElementMenu();
addAttributeMenu();

// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {

    // If the clicked element is not the menu
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

        // Hide it
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    }
});


// If the menu element is clicked
$(".custom-menu li").click(function () {

    // This is the triggered action name
    switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {

        // A case for each action. Your actions here
        case "duplicate":
            duplicateItem(clicked);
            break;
        case "delete":
            deleteItem(clicked);
            break;
        case "copy":
            copyItem(clicked);
            break;
        case "cut":
            cutItem(clicked);
            break;
        case "paste":
            pasteItem();
            break;
    }

    // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

function addElementMenu() {
    $('.element').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();

        //set clicked item
        clicked = $(this);
        parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        console.log(clicked);
        console.log(parent);
        // Show contextmenu
        $("#elementMenu").finish().show().css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px",
            display: 'block'
        });
    });
}

function addAttributeMenu() {
    $('.attribute').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();

        //set clicked item
        clicked = $(this);
        parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        console.log(clicked);
        console.log(parent);
        // Show contextmenu
        $("#attributeMenu").finish().show().css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px",
            display: 'block'
        });
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.attribute {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.element {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='attribute' id="attributeID">
    <div class='element' id="elementID"></div>
</div>
<ul class='custom-menu' id="elementMenu">
    <li class='visibleElement' data-action="duplicate">Duplicate</li>
    <li class='visibleElement' data-action="delete">Delete</li>
    <li class='visibleElement' data-action="copy">Copy</li>
    <li class='visibleElement' data-action="cut">Cut</li>
    <li class='visibleAttribute' data-action="paste">Paste</li>
</ul>
<ul class='custom-menu' id='attributeMenu'>
    <li class='visibleAttribute' data-action="paste">Paste</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"As of jQuery 1.7, [the .on() method is the preferred method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) for attaching event handlers to a document."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stopPropagation()`, this way when you right-click on the children is not going to trigger the event in the parent div.

script:

```
function addElementMenu() {
    $('.element').bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();

        // Avoid the event from bubbling up to parent
        event.stopPropagation();

        //set clicked item
        clicked = $(this);
        parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        console.log(clicked);
        console.log(parent);
        // Show contextmenu
        $("#elementMenu").finish().show().css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px",
            display: 'block'
        });
    });
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/mp2vaLhy/)